# Installing Ubuntu, Windows and Phoenix OS

Tags: windows-10, grubrescue

So I had installed Windows 10 and Phoenix OS previously and everything was fine. But recently I had to use Ubuntu as well so I wiped everything and performed a fresh installation but as soon as I installed Phoenix OS (I had installed Windows first and then Ubuntu and it was working perfectly) I was brought to the grub rescue screen. I got out of it but the solution I found online and now it is showing me five options like previously (ubuntu, Advanced options, 2 memory tests and Windows 10) but when I boot in Windows, it boots Phoenix OS instead. How can I boot in Windows again? And is there a way so that grub can show Phoenix OS as a separate option? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: " it boots Phoenix OS instead. How can I boot in Windows again?" Neither of these are Ubuntu. Ubuntu is working fine so that makes this off topic.  have you tried boot repair? That is the go-to tool for this.

Comment: Just one point: You seem to use legacy boot mode which makes it difficult since you can have only one boot-loader in MBR. If your machine supports UEFI, make the switch to UEFI, you'd have to start over though, convert drive to GPT and install all three OS again. That would have some advantages, no need for extended partition, all boot-loaders would coexist in the ESP, so you would be always able to boot any OS via efi boot menu. I don't know Phoenix and if it supports UEFI, you could use other OS such as PrimeOS instead.

Comment: @mook765 i'll try this out

Comment: @Rinzwind yes I know but I thought the issue was with grub that's why I posted it here

Comment: @UsmanMani There are also installers as `.iso` available, maybe that's better than the `.exe` which would have to be run from Windows.